# Kurento 6 with Plumber Endpoint

Tags: webrtc, kurento

Has anyone try the plumber endpoint function on KMS 6?
Does KMS 6 support Pulmber Endpoint?

If yes, can please provide the pulmber endpoint performance?
Such as streaming latency on second KMS?(quality, max connection number..)
And what kind of server running the KMS 6 ?(CPU, RAM, OS..)

How can I get the plumber endpoint installed on my KMS 6?

Answer (score 0):

PlumberEndpoint is under heavy refactorization since KMS v5.1 and it is not available since that version. The PlumberEndpoint issued after that refactorization shall probably not be released to the public as open source. Hence, KMS v6.0 shall most probably not have PlumberEndpoint either.